# How come UIKit doesn't have UIMatrix, UIButtonCell class like AppKit's NSMatrix, NSButtonCell?

Tags: uikit

I find AppKit's `NSMatrix` and `NSButtonCell` classes useful for grids of buttons. I wonder why Apple never created these counterparts for UIKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in iOS is [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/). It's much more flexible and useful than NSMatrix, here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1).

Comment: Very good ... `UICollectionViewCell` would be analogous to `NSCell`... I see this wasn't introduced until iOS 6. I have yet to use it. I could use it to write something akin to [minesweeper](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs224/archive/projects/minesweeper/minesweeper/minesweeper.pdf) for iOS.

Comment: Indeed uses cells instead of views, which makes it more reusable and speed efficient. You could build anything from minesweeper to a circular menu.